# Signing a kenel driver that is built with MinGW, gcc

Tags: gcc, mingw, windows-kernel

I've made my own driver for kernel-level memory management, it's built with MinGW using gcc, written in c.
I am producing a normal .sys file, but in-order to load it I need to boot windows in test-signing mode which does not require a certificate to load, how do I sign my driver?

Clarifying a bit: msvc (or Visual C/C++ have it's own signing tools, to test or even use drivers on other computer, can MinGW do something like that, and if not, is there an easy way to sign a driver so that the certificate can be shipped along with the program easily as that.

Comment: Check out this link: https://myworks2012.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/how-to-compile-windows-x64-driver-using-mingw-w64-gcc/

Comment: That link is helpful in terms of compiling the driver, but I didn't see any certificates being generated.

Comment: Nothing? At all?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode for a tool to sign your code without using MSVC. I also found the following link which shows how you can generate the actual certificate: https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/